# Certificate conflict on http

Tags: linux, apache, http, ssl, ssl-certificate

I recently got a hosting provider from US to host one of my websites. Everything is good besides the fact that when I first tested my website from my phone and tablet I got some strange warnings.

```
//Website format:
http://www.mywebsite.com
```

On the phone I got this alert:

```
Service www.mywebsite.com sent a certificate with a different name than the one you asked for. Accept like this?
```

And the detail descriptions:

```
WebSite:
www.mywebsite.com

Issuer:
AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
GlobalSign nv-sa, BE

Subject:
*.fcomet.com, Domain Control
Validated, fcomet.com

Key utilisation:
undefined

Valability from 08.09.2015 to 08.09.2016

Certificate format:
X.509

Algoritm:
SHA2RSA

Serial number:
//some long code here

Digital sign SHA1
//some long code here

Digital sign MD5
//some long code here
```

On the tablet I did not get all the message but it was something with a certificate also and some aditional text which I noted:

```
google-analytics.com
Google Inc

Serial number:
//some serial number here

Sent by:
Google Internet Authority G2
Google Inc

Valid from 13.07.2016 to 05.10.2016
```

What bothers me is that I can not reproduce this "bug" again. On my phone I pressed `accept only this time` but even if I enter the website again I don't get that message anymore (in order to send a screenshot to the hosting provider because he sais that I should not get this error at all). I even cleaned the cache from my mobile devices and also from my website because I use a Wordpress and I cleaned the cache from Nginx Cache, WP Super Cache and Autoptimize.

*What I suspect is that the hosting provider try to make some redirects to https or something like that, I can't explain.*

If I try to enter on my website using `https` I get this message:
    Your connection is not secure
    The owner of www.mywebsite.com has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

If I press `Advanced` button I get some detalis:

```
www.mywebsite.com usses an incorect security certificate 
The certificate is valid only for this names:
*.fcomet.com, fcomet.com 
Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

If I add and confirm the exception I will be redirected successful to `https://www.mywebsite.com`, a blank page with this text `Index of /`. This seem strange because on any other website I enter and try to change the http protocol to https I won't be alowed to access the website with https protocol.

I also tried to test my website [here](http://www.responsimulator.com) and [here](http://ipadpeek.com/) but it does not work, I get a white page. If I test with any other website, I get the website content. Mabey this will help you to understand what is the problem.

Does somebody have any ideea what is the problem here and how can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: This is off topic here and should be asked on serverfault. It looks like your certificate is incorrect but you've not told us what your website url actually is and the description of your certificate has been dumbed down to the point of being meaningless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as per comment above

Comment: I apreciate that you shared you point of view here before pressing the close button. I am an active member only on stackoverflow that's why I posted this question here. If you think I might get an answer in another place I am very happy to add the question there. You shoudn't mark this question to close it because I can close it my self if you speak kind and tell me where are the biggest chances to get a solution for this problem, as I already said I am happy to post it in other place.

Comment: Regarding the url, I want to keep it private. I don't have any certificate, I did not set anything, I booked a hosting and created a wordpress blog, that's all. I posted here what I actually got and I did not knew if this info is helpful or not for you but I was hoping to be helpful.